# DatePipe changes the date incorrectly

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am observing, what seems like, a strange behavior when using DatePipe in angular2. For some reason, after running date '03/**09**/1992' through a DatePipe, it is changed to '03/**08**/1992':

http://plnkr.co/edit/SK6Z9q8h7EqunmkqVtpt

*(updated code: bug fix)*

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div> Invalid Date: {{ somedate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</div>
    <div> DateObject: {{ dateType }}</div>
    <div> DateObject With Pipe: {{ dateType | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</div>
    <br>
    <div> Other Valid Dates </div>
    <div>{{ afterdate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</div>
    <div>{{ dateTypeAfter }}</div>

    <div>{{ beforedate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</div>
    <div>{{ dateTypeBefore }}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  somedate:string;
  afterdate: string;
  beforedate: string;
  dateType: Date;
  dateTypeAfter: Date;
  dateTypeBefore: Date;

  constructor() {
    this.somedate = '03/09/1992';
    this.afterdate = '03/09/1993';
    this.beforedate = '03/09/1991';
    this.dateType = new Date(this.somedate);
    this.dateTypeAfter = new Date(this.afterdate);
    this.dateTypeBefore = new Date(this.beforedate);
  }
}
```

This does not happen for year 1991 or 1993, as shown above. Result:

```
Invalid Date: 03/08/1992
DateObject: Mon Mar 09 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
DateObject With Pipe: 03/08/1992

Other Valid Dates
03/09/1993
Tue Mar 09 1993 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
03/09/1991
Sat Mar 09 1991 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: Plunker shows correct dates for me :D

Comment: So when you view it, you see the first line as: "Invalid Date: 03/09/1992"?

Comment: Yes, exactly http://imgur.com/Dn2y3lK I think the Angular Datepipe is a bit buggy (still?) at least it was at some point. Haven't had to work with it in a while :)

Comment: Interesting. I just checked in IE and it is working fine in IE -_-

Comment: What interests me is the timezone difference between `this.dateType` and the other two. If you run inside of the Developer Tools of the browsers: `new Date(1991, 2, 9)` and the same for the other years (remember month is 0-based); what do you see? There shouldn't be a timezone difference according to [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=1993) link.

Comment: That's a good catch. It seems that the problem is the timezone difference. It recognizes the daylight savings and applies GMT-0400 for 1992. This is not the case, however, for the other years, so the universal time is GMT-0500. Because the time is static (00:00:00), the case that GMT-0400 is used, it is interpreted as 11:00 PM on 3/8/1992 (because that is what it would be, if we are reading universally and ignoring daylight savings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually daylight savings zones.

```
Mon Mar 09 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Tue Mar 09 1993 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Sat Mar 09 1991 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Notice that the GMT offsets are different and it looks like the date pipe will pay attention to that. This makes the date 03/09/1992 actually translate to 03/08/1992 23:00:00 PM.

One possible approach right now that applies to me (but has it's own problems) is to use UTC:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(1992, 2, 9, 5, 0, 0));
```

The above will ensure that the offset time is 5 and standardized across time zones.